# Extracting data from website using VBA returns same value over and over

Tags: excel, vba

So i have this problem.
This code should grab an URL from a spreadsheet, open it and extract a specific data.
Than it should go down one row, grab another URL and do the same thing.
But it only returns the value of the first search...
what am i doing wrong? Here are 4 urls

1. https://www.sitemercado.com.br/laranjao/jose-bonifacio-loja-sao-jose-sao-jose-avenida-joaquim-moreira-silva/arroz-tipo-1-prato-fino-embalagem-1kg
2. https://www.sitemercado.com.br/laranjao/jose-bonifacio-loja-sao-jose-sao-jose-avenida-joaquim-moreira-silva/arroz-tipo-1-prato-fino-pacote-5kg
3. https://www.sitemercado.com.br/laranjao/jose-bonifacio-loja-sao-jose-sao-jose-avenida-joaquim-moreira-silva/arroz-tipo-1-rosalito-pacote-5kg
4. https://www.sitemercado.com.br/laranjao/jose-bonifacio-loja-sao-jose-sao-jose-avenida-joaquim-moreira-silva/arroz-tipo-1-rosalito-extra-premium-pacote-1kg

[Printscreen from spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S8Q0.jpg)

```
   Sub a()

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Top = 0
objIE.Left = 0
objIE.Width = 800
objIE.Height = 600
objIE.Visible = False 'We will see the window navigation

On Error Resume Next

Dim i As Long
For i = 15 To 19

linkprod = Range("A" & i)

objIE.navigate (linkprod)

Do
DoEvents

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        objIE.Quit
        Set objIE = Nothing

    End If
Loop Until objIE.readystate = 4

txtHtml.Text = objIE.document.body.innerhtml
objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("kg")(0).innerText
 Text = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("kg")(0).innerText
    Range("k" & i) = Text


Next i

End Sub
```